# How to switch to a different date format?

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

> **Original Question**
>   How to format the date correctly?

I need to change date in this format - `Fri Jul 12 2019`
to this format `Friday, 12 Jule`.

I have tried using [date-fns](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns)

*(Reason: An element has a date attribute in this format)*

Comment: use moment js to change

Comment: momentJS is the best plugin to do this. You could find it here: https://momentjs.com

Comment: @MohammadBagheri why should momentjs compared to date-fns be the better choice or the best library. date-fns was created due to some design flaws of momentjs.

Comment: @t.niese well in my opinion momentJS is very simple and easy to use. I have not used fate-fns and whatever I have needed so far has been done by momentJS. This is my personal opinion.

Comment: @MohammadBagheri then you shouldn't say that it is the best library.

Comment: This question has been asked [*many, many times before*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+reformat+date+string). Please search before creating a new question. Also many duplicates using [*date-fns*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D%5Bdate-fns%5D+format+date).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `date-fns`

```js
const date = "Fri Jul 12 2019"
const dateFormat = 'dddd, DD MMMM';
console.log(dateFns.format(new Date(date),dateFormat));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.min.js"></script>
```

It would recommend use of library like `momentjs`

```js
const date = "Fri Jul 12 2019"
const dateFormat = 'dddd, DD MMMM';
console.log(moment(new Date(date)).format(dateFormat));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: When using a library for formatting, it should also be used for parsing. Fri Jul 12 2019 is not a format supported for parsing by ECMA-262 (though it is the format for [*toDateString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-date.prototype.todatestring)), so results are implementation dependent. Also, `moment(new Date(date))` should produce identical results to `moment(date)` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse yourself the date with pure JS if you want :

```
    var dateToParse = 'Fri Jul 12 2019';
var dateParsed = new Date(dateToParse);

const days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
const months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
  'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'
];

document.write(days[dateParsed.getDay()] + ', ' + dateParsed.getDate() + ' ' + months[dateParsed.getMonth()]);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Beowulf59/o37maj1b/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use MomentJs easy to change the date formats

```js
const date = "Fri Jul 12 2019"
const dateFormat = 'dddd, DD MMMM';
console.log("New Date Format is",moment(new Date(date)).format(dateFormat));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing Date format using date_fns

```
const date = "Fri Jul 12 2019"
const format = 'dddd, DD MMMM';
const newdate = dateFns.format(new Date(date),format);
console.log(newdate);
```

Calling CDN

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.min.js"></script>
```